# Character from csv file is unknown although the same typed from keyboard is recognized

Tags: java, csv

There is a csv file containing special characters such as `²`. When displaying the csv lines through my code then I get `?` :

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(csv, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for(String line : lines) {
    String[] champs = line.split(";");
    String designation = champs[1];
    System.out.println("========================== designation = "+designation);
}
```

Although when I display a variable containing the `²` character typed from keyboard then everything is ok. So what is wrong ?

Comment: The CSV file you have isn't encoded with UTF_8.

Comment: Or the terminal that prints the output has a different encoding.

Comment: After re-saving the csv as to be utf-8 encoded , then the special character appeared correctly !